# Eclipse Debugging Java Servlet (with Tomcat) Connect to a Server through SSL

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ssl

I'm working on a server that need to connect to an LDAP server through SSL. The connection requires the javax.net.ssl.trustStore. I have configured everything to be on the correct place. Every thing is working perfect once I deploy that servlet on Tomcat container. There's no any problem at all.

But, when I put these codes into the eclipse and using eclipse Tomcat server (It means that I deploy the same code, the same configurations and the same environment on eclipse), every time I run the code, there is always an exception at the connection as below:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: IP-Address:Port-Number [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:218)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2740)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.<init>(InitialDirContext.java:101)
at ldap.LdapTool.init(LdapTool.java:53)
at ldap.LdapTool.<init>(LdapTool.java:36)
at beans.LdapUserGroups.<init>(LdapUserGroups.java:9)
at org.apache.jsp.Organisations_jsp._jspService(Organisations_jsp.java:80)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any one has any clues for this?

Comment: As I see you cannot connect to the LDAP from your localhost server. Does the LDAP server needs authentication? Yes. Do you have some kind of credential on you server(Tomcat)? I suppose you don't. Look for this.

Comment: Thx Thrash, Yes LDAP server requires authentication to access it, and yes, there is a credential on my tomcat server. If I build a war file and deploy it into my tomcat server then it works perfectly fine. the problem occur only if I run that code straight from the eclipse. I have also copied all config files from tomcat server into the eclipse server, but it is still not working.

Comment: Did you have to add a certificate to the keystore? If yes, are you sure that you are using the same JRE when running from Eclipse than the JRE used by standalone Tomcat? Keystores are per JRE. Maybe when Tomcat runs from Eclipse it is using the JRE configured for Eclipse.

Comment: I already double check that JRE. To check JRE in Eclipse is open Project's Properties, Choose Java Build Path and Click on Libraries tab, then Look at JRE Library System. To check JRE using in my machine, I run this command: readlink -f $(which java).
both are the same /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.45/jre

Comment: In Eclipse the JRE used for build in not necessarily the same used for server. Look under Windows, Preferences, then in section Server, Runtime Environments, select Tomcat, then Edit, and see JRE field.